Does Primed Magick count for having less than 100% Magick for The Huntress Arcana Card?
The Huntress Arcana card is:

While you have less than 100% Magick, your Attack and Special deal +30% damage.

I'm nearly exceeding my Grasp and removing the Huntress would give me more room, but not sure it's worth it, since I'm mainly Priming my Magick away (removing a certain number of Max Magicka) instead of casting things.
So I need to know if Priming is activating The Huntress to decide.
